# Remove characters after multiple points "..."

Tags: r, stringr

I have strings like these:

```
text <- c("11. Availability...17", "1. Turnover...7")
```

I want:

```
c("11. Availability", "1. Turnover")
```

My idea is to remove everything behind/including the "..." .
Unfotunately I'm not able to fix it with gsub() or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
gsub('\\.\\.\\..*', '', text)
#[1] "11. Availability" "1. Turnover"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
gsub('\\.{2}.*', '', text)
[1] "11. Availability" "1. Turnover" 
# or
 gsub('\\.{2,3}.*', '', text)
[1] "11. Availability" "1. Turnover"
#where 3 has no impact on this, but useful for further cases
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
gsub('\\.{2,}\\d+$', '', c("11. Availability...17", "1. Turnover...7"))
[1] "11. Availability" "1. Turnover"
```